# Sidekiq monitor and nginx

Tags: ruby, nginx, sidekiq, grape-api, sidekiq-monitor

I am running Nginx, Sidekiq Monitor in the context of a Grape API application.  I have Sinatra in my Gemfile.  I also set up a rake task to run Sidekiq monitor:

```
  namespace :sidekiq do
    task :monitor do
      require 'sidekiq/web'
      app = Sidekiq::Web
      app.set :environment, :production
      app.set :bind, '0.0.0.0'
      app.set :port, 9494
      app.run!
    end
  end
```

I found this is the way to run sidekiq without Rails.  Next I set up Nginx to send requests from the web to Sidekiq on port 9494:

```
server {
  server_name localhost;

  listen 9494;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

  location /sidekiq {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    # pass to the upstream unicorn server mentioned above
    proxy_pass http://unicorn;
  }
}
```

Next, I run the rake task to start the sidekiq monitor.  Finally, I go to the IP address of the web server and use the port to try and access the sidekiq monitor.  Unfortunately I get an error "web page is not available."

Reviewing the nginx logs I am not even getting an entry in the access logs like my request is even hitting nginx.  I have tried a multitude of server_name entries (the IP address, localhost, etc.).  Nothing seems to work.  If I do:

```
curl -vvv http://localhost:9494
```

I get the proper HTML output to the terminal.  So I am fairly confident it is an issue with the request from the server -> nginx -> unicorn.

Any ideas on what else I can check?

**UPDATE:**
  I have tried removing the configuration from nginx and hitting the sidekiq monitor with the IP and port without success.  I also removed the app.set :port, 9494 from the configuration and tried that as well without success.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Right now you have both configured to use port 9494.  That can't work.

Comment: Hello Mike, thanks for the tip.  I removed it in the rake task, restarted nginx and it still does not work.  I am assuming I need to port forward from 9494 (configured in nginx) to the port that the rake task is running on?  When I started the rake task it started on a port 4567.  If I don't even use nginx and access the port via a browser it doesn't work either.